# How to "unnest" a data frame with data frame columns

Tags: r, json, dataframe, tidyr

I am familiar with using `unnest()` for data frame list columns but it does not work for data frame columns. Now I am dealing with a data frame with nested data frame columns. Code below will provide an example (this is the accuweather test api, I am generating similar data with my api key). Look at the temperature column as an example.

```
library(jsonlite) 
dat <- fromJSON("http://apidev.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/329381.json?language=en&apikey=hoArfRosT1215")
```

`flatten()` does not work-- at least not by itself. It gives me a long list with redundant items not a data frame.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Have you tried `rbindlist()`?

Comment: I may not be using it correctly as I've never heard of this function before, but when I stick the results of my code above into `rbindlist()` I get an error: Error in rbindlist(dat) : 
  Item 1 of input is not a data.frame, data.table or list

Answer (score 2):

I've done some weather API work myself, and have had great success using the

`flatten()` function from jsonlite

`dat <- dat %>% flatten()` should do the trick!

Comment: I should've mentioned (and i will update the Q) - flatten() gave me really bad results, a super long list with a lot of redundant items.

Comment: What would your desired output look like?

Comment: I would be fine with what you see when you view(), eg, temperature.metric.value as a column. In this case I think I want 15 total columns - 10 that are there, plus taking the temperature column and splitting it into 6 new columns.

Comment: I don't understand how what you've described is different from the output of `flatten()`? From your example data `flatten()` returns a dataframe with 15 columns. Is there a difference between the example data and your real data that's missing?